# Shiny Dashboard DropdownMenu MessageItem Click

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Is there a way to bind a click action to a messageItem?
I know that one can bind a href attribute, but that will not do it in my case.
There must be a way to listen to a menu item click - that should be an obvious action/attribute.

```
output$exportMenu <- renderMenu({
dropdownMenu(type = "messages",
             icon = icon("file-export"),
             messageItem(
               from = "Rawdata",
               message = "All data",
               icon = icon("file-export")
             ),
             messageItem(
               from = "Filterdata",
               message = "Data with Filtes",
               icon = icon("file-export"),
               href = "./?some=Filter"
             )
)})
```

Comment: If I could add an id to the messageItem I could add any action like this: *onclick("potentialId", function(event) { print(event) })* but that is impossible as well. Seriously - how can this be, it renders this menu useless to a big extend.

Comment: A function that lets you add onClicks to .class and the click-event transmitting its target would do the trick as well ...